# Posting short messages to twitter and long messages to gmail using ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, gmail, android-intent

Using ACTION_SEND it's possible to post messages to various sharing services such as gmail, facebook, twitter, etc.  Most services have reasonably long message lengths, but twitter in particular is very short (140 characters).

Not knowing in advance which service a user is going to select once the Intent.createChooser() dialog appears, is there a way to construct an intent that will result in a short message for twitter but a longer message for other services?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try to Seperate Share with twitter as a option in your application. Get the text internally from your application in some edittext box validate and check whether  its less than 140 characters and then send the text. Even in this case the users will be able to see all options when you call `ACTION_SEND` but they will be at least restricted to 140 characters.

```
Intent i=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, R.string.share_subject);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, ...);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, R.string.share_title));
```

You can also try using Bit ly API that can shorten URLs that are being posted on twitter

Comment: Thanks, that's similar to a solution I'd already thought of, which is to use two different buttons with different intents (one for twitter, one for everything else), and use a shortened text in the second.  But twitter will show up as a send option in the first, which isn't ideal.

Comment: Though the option shows up there the possibility of an user to select twitter client from that page will be very less since he has not selected that option...If at all he does that it would be his fault.Since we do not have a direct method to select applications that can post messages on twitter we don't have an hand over it... May be the future SDK's can provide us with such options. Some users may be knowing this :)

Comment: @DeRagan Twitter automatically shortens URLs using t.co domain. So the url you post won't count its entire length